# Blade view not reflected in browser, even after storage clear using Nwidart/Laravel-modules

Tags: module, laravel-5.8

My changes are not reflecting inside browser even after `storage/framework/views` clear and running various artisan clean-up commands.

To make clear that I am calling the right file.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible my PHP environment is somehow persistent loading this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I am using Nwidart/LaravelModules to structure my project.

Laravel Modules has a command that publishes all modules to the views folder in resources/views. Apparently Laravel was using those 'published modules' alongside the 'official' modules, which caused the problem above.